# How to recreate vuejs composant with ajax data on specific event

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am newbie in vuejs. I want to reload component items according to another choice.
Example: I want to reload posts list according to tag/category user selected.
How can I do it? where do I need to put a new ajax call?
Also ajax call is different from tags to categories.
I think add ajax call in **`created`** method like simple component loaded on page loading will not help. How to do this?
thanks

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="pt-2 pb-3">
        <input type="hidden" name="my_variable" v-model="myVar" @change="foo">
    </div>
  </div>
  </template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myVar: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function(e) {},
    async foo() {
        console.log('foo', this.myVar);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, there's no point into listening to a `@change` event on a hidden `<input>` bound to a reactive property. Not that it wouldn't work, but you can use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers). Whenever you can do something without using or manipulating DOM, that's the way to go. Second of all, how are you getting the posts in the first place? And what's the relation between Vue, the database and the page being rendered? Your code shows you haven't made any effort or research.

Comment: this is not the entire code. it is showing the basic which I cannot make work. I remove ajx request and other. I try to do step my step to check what is wrong. Maybe the good programmers think that this is stupid, but that is why I try to understand my errors and learn more. thank anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you have the tag/category in the instanciation of the component then yeah, you can make the call in the `created` lifecycle.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    options: []
  }),
  methods: {
    async getOptions(){
       const response = await axios.get('/items');

       this.options = response.data
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't have the tags in the creation of the component and need to change when the user selects a category you can do the ajax call when the user changes the options:

```
<template>
  <select v-model="optionSelected" @change="getOptions">
    <option value="1">First Value</option>
    <option value="2">Second Value</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    optionSelected: null,
    options: [],
  }),
  methods: {
     async getOptions(item) {
        const response = await axios.get('/items', { params: { filter: item } });
        
        this.options = response.data;
     }
  }
}

</script>
```

---

*Edit after OP updated question*

When you have an `input`, every time the user inputs something the browser emits an event called `input`. When you have a `select` element, the browser emits an event called `change`. In this case since you are using an `input` we should be using `@input` and not `@change`

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_variable" v-model="myVar" @input="foo">
```

You can read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Besides that when you listen to an `input` event the first parameter of the function will be the value passed:

```
async foo(value) {
        console.log(value, this.myVar);
    }
```

Comment: I have method declared for @change, but whatever I do, it is not triggered. What can be the issue?

Comment: @Cutis can you update your question with code example?

Comment: Like i said I am newbie. I have updated my question with the code. thanks

Comment: @Charlie, why not `watch: { myVar(val) { console.log(val); }}`? You don't need a DOM element for it, unless something external to Vue changes the `value` of that `<input>` and `@input` is just a method of capturing that change, but even in that scenario, there are better ways to do it (you can basically target the Vue instance directly and set its `.myVar` instead of changing `value` of the hidden input).

Comment: @tao you are right. It is much better indeed. Thank you

Comment: @Charlie thanks. thank for ‘@input‘. I was using change according to jquery events. Now I will pay attention. When I use input type text and I try, I get my variable in console. but when it is input hidden, even if value change, no output with console.log. what is the explanation please?

Comment: @Cutis I would avise you to start a new question. Feel free to post the link here so I can help you but you can't keep going a question like this. Questions in Stackoverflow should be short and only address one issue. If this question helped you, please mark it as correct